Ошибка в запуске sent_tokenize() библиотеки nlkt
Не работает токенизация библиотеки nltk (функция sent_tokenize(), кстати word_tokenize() тоже не работает) и не понятно почему. Библиотека вроде установлена, вызов функции как в документации, так что меня вводит в ступор сообщение об ошибке.


Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
